# Is it possible to store an attribute foreign key in django models?

Tags: sql, django, django-models

In SQL, you can have a table attribute be a foreign key, where that foreign key is the attribute of the referenced table.

In Django Models, the `models.ForeignKey()` references an object. Is it possible to reference the fields instead of the object? If not, how should one go about designing models in a way where we can use referenced object.

For instance, if I had the following tables. I could do this in SQL:

```
             pk
courseList(course_id, course_title, professor, day, time)

                               pk
TutoringClassList(course_id, tutor_id)
```

Here, `course_id` in `TutoringClassList` is the foreign key to the `course_id` in `courseList`

However, Django would have something like this for `TutoringClassList`

```
TutoringClassList(course, tutor)
```

Where `course` is a model foreign key object referencing the `courseList`, and `tutor` (we assume there is a `TutorList` model created as well), is also a model object referencing the `TutorList`

## END GOAL

I want to store the attribute of the foreign key instead of the object. If I can't do that, what is the best way to manipulate that attribute value for that object?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, can you give an example of what you would like to achieve? You can access the raw value of a `ForeignKey` field by appending `_id` to the field name if that is what you mean?

Comment: You can pass the raw value of a `ForeignKey` instead of the object in Django: `TutoringClassList(course_id=course.id, tutor_id=tutor.id)`

Comment: @IainShelvington so would that look like this: `course_id = course.id` instead of `course = models.ForeignKey(course, on_delete....)`

Comment: You want to define a `ForeignKey` but not pass the referenced model?

Comment: Yes. A `ForeignKey` to the attribute, like it would in `sql`. Assuming that's possible

Comment: You can override the field on the related table that a `ForeignKey` references if that's what you want to do? You can't have a `ForeignKey` that is not to a model

Answer (score 0):

```
class TutoringClassList(models.Model):
   course = models.ForeignKey(courseList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   tutor = models.ForeignKey(TutorList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This method is using Foreignkey
OR
You can pass the raw value of a ForeignKey instead of the object in Django:

```
TutoringClassList(course_id=course.id, tutor_id=tutor.id)
```

Comment: Are there any flaws with doing the second one? Is it considered good practice?